# d3 choropleth map javascript switching json data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have set a choropleth map to retrieve data from a json file, and have each municipality in the map to render its colors accordingly.

I am now stuck trying to write a javascript function to switch over to a new set of data from a separate JSON file without having to reload the map.

The sample code works for just one JSON file but I have another set of data in another JSON file with different values to the same "ID", I would like to have the user switch between JSON files through radio buttons or on-click.

```
d3.json("indicator1.json", function(data) {
var pad = d3.format(""),
  quantize = d3.scale.quantile().domain([0, 15]).range(d3.range(9));

d3.json("new_map.json", function(json) {
municipalities.selectAll("path", "id", "name")
  .data(json.features)
  .enter().append("svg:path")
  .attr("class", function(d) { return "q" + quantize(data[pad(d.id)]) + "-9"; })
  .attr("d", path)
  .append("svg:title")
  .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name + ": " + data[pad(d.id)] + "%"; });
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better off combining both data sets into a single json, and using a button/click event to switch between the attributes of your json object...